# emgu cv plugin for visual studio

Tags: c#

I am using emgucv plugin for visual studio to develop a project that uses my webcam. the project runs fine in windows for application. But when I use import the project to my WPF and run it, it just displays the imagebox but does not show the web cam. Please what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because to display the images WPF doesn't use `PictureBox` or `ImageBox` .

You can convert the individual frame to a bitmap and then update the Image .

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
srcImg.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(myImage);
```

BitmapSourceConvert class:

```
 public static class BitmapSourceConvert
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32")]
        private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

        public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap();

                BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    ptr,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                DeleteObject(ptr);
                return bs;
            }
        }
    }
```